# OSLO masterpage corrupt?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I had added and then removed a small snippet of code that was suppose to remove the title on each page of my SharePoint Online site. Since then when I use the OSLO masterpage some of the apps and code snippets do not show up. If I use seattle they work fine though, is there a way to reset the OSLO masterpage to default code or does anyone have the code I could just paste over what's in my designer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out in Site Settings, Reset to site definition:

> If you want to remove all customizations from a page (such as changes to Web Part zones or text added to the page) you can use this feature to reset to the version of the page included with the site definition.
>
> You can reset a single page within your site to use the version of the page included in the site definition, or you can reset all pages.
>
> Caution: When you reset to the site definition version, you will lose all customizations made to the current version of the page. No backup copy of the page will be made before the page is updated, and no new version is created.

Alternatively, you can download Oslo from another site. if you can't get to another one, try creating a sub site and download it from there.

Comment: If I reset to site definition will that totally remove all my web parts and content on the pages?

Comment: try just pointing it to your master page. Fair warning, I haven't tried this, but I'd guess it should work. Do you have a dummy site you can try it on? If you're concerned, take the 2nd option and find Oslo elsewhere ;)

Comment: I've been searching and can't find Oslo anywhere on the web . I tried copying it from another site collection however Designer tells me it is unable to change anything on the page.

Comment: Browse to the master page gallery through a web browser, then you can download the master page, and then upload it into your problem site

Comment: I got it, I followed your suggestion of resetting the site definition for the entire site and that seems to have fixed it.